# Basic binning software for data analysis (no coding)

Tags: graphs, data-analysis

I have a set of data (X and Y) and I need to do the following two types of binning:

Procedure A (constant steps)

- Finds the max and min in X
- Divide this interval in a number of bins chosen by me
- For each bin it creates a new set X, say X', where each entry is the central point of each bin (for "central" I mean the following: if I have (0,0,0,1,1) the central is 0.5)
- Of all the points falling in a bin, it takes the mean and standard deviation, and writes these two set of datas in Y' and another column for the error

Procedure B (constant information)

- Does the same thing but this time instead of fixing the number of bins, it allows me to fix the number of points per bin. However the X intervals should be calculated in the following way: if I have (3 ; 3.5 ; 4 ; 4.5 ; 5 ; 5.5) and I want three datas per bin the results should be (3 ; 3.5 ; 4) and ( 4 ; 4.5 ; 5) discarding 5 (so not (3 ; 3.5 ; 4) and ( 4.5 ; 5 ; 5.5) otherwise there is a hole of 0.5 between 4 and 4.5)

Is there a way to do these two calculations with a software?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do these two calculations with a software?

Yes.

Assuming that you are OK to pay money in order to avoid doing (much if any) coding, I recommend Igor Pro. Search the IgorExchange site for questions along the lines of what you ask.

Assuming that you want to do it (mostly or almost entirely) for free and you are not really all that serious about not doing your own coding, then you might try sage, python, GNU Octave, R, ... or any other free data analysis packages.